# Upload Images to Laravel-Lumen API

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

With my API i need to upload images from mobile app to my server and save the image path to database  so i have the following issues :

- Where to save the images? I tried to save them in the storage/app
  under images folder (which is work fine)

  ```
     public function fileUpload(Request $request) {


     if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
         $image = $request->file('image');
         $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $destinationPath = storage_path('/app/images');
         $image->move($destinationPath, $name);


         return response()->json(['data'=>"image is uploaded"]);
     }
  ```

  }

  and make a symbolic link to this folder in the public folder but its
  not working due to access permission error which will lead to the
  other issue.
- What permission should i gave to the storage folder to make the whole
  operation works save the images and the saved link is readable (even 777 didn't work) **Access forbidden!**

  sudo chmod -R 777 storage

Any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try with `755` ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work as well

Comment: Try with `chmod -R 0777 storage` (notice 0777). Also try `php artisan storage:link`.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` command not found There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Storage directory is not open to user's requests, public directory is, you need to create a symbolic link from storage directory to public directory:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command will create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`, in this case you can store your file under `storage/app/public` and make it accessible from the web too:

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$image->storeAs('public', $name); // => storage/app/public/file.img
URL::asset('storage/'.$name); // => http://example.com/stoage/file.img
```

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` command not found There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.

Comment: I think lumen doesn't support this command, it's a lightweight version of laravel, you may want to create symlink manually `ln -s storage/app/public public/storage` **Or** you can create `images` folder under public directory, and change its owner to the web server user `www-data` :   `chown -R www-data:your_user images` and then store uploded files under images directory like this: `$image->storeAs('images', $name);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments, well this is the issue with lumen the Filesystem functions are not exist  `$image->storeAs('images', $name)` will through Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory] is not instantiable and even base_path() is not valid in lumen and thats why i asked about the best folder to save images

Comment: for windows users, this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) show how to create symlink manually using `mklink` command

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you try to create a folder in the public folder and store your files there. You can use base_path()."/public/uploads"

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store the images would inside the storage folder and create a symbolic link in the public folder.

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage` should work. Make sure you are accessing the right url.

To access the image you should use something like the below urls. My folder structure looks like /storage/app/public/images/user/avatar/

Local: http://localhost/project-name/public/storage/images/user/avatar/HdXzVnKxzUSdAssvXaoM2n0ixzEEG7jlK8acLiHV.png

Production: http://example.com/storage/images/user/avatar/3133L07guCv8shINNZM30c2Ux1HdfpFt04YdLRpf.png

You can check this gist to figure out if you are missing something: https://gist.github.com/danish-shaikh/9c328288a817309f93238c6b5d48ed7e